# Is it safe to remove history.back() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, blackberry, jquery-mobile

On a blackberry browser the history.back(); function redirects the browser back two steps instead (on blackberry browser running OS5.0) of the previous page, in this case #firstpage. So I just remove the call to history.back(); and it works. By works I mean the browser goes to previous page - #firstpage. I'm wondering though if this is correct and im not inadvertently causing unexpected behaviour on a browser I havent tested on. , is it safe to do this across all browsers ?

```
<div data-role="page" id="firstpage">
        <div id="headerItem" data-role="header" data-theme="b">
                <h4>Header</h4>
                <a data-rel='external' data-ajax="false" href='' class='ui-btn-right' data-icon='home'>Home</a>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content"  data-theme="b" id="links"></div>

        <div class="footerDate" data-role="footer" data-theme="b"></div> 
</div>

<div id="secondpage" data-role="page" >
        <div id="headerDiv" data-role="header" data-theme="b">
              <a href='#' class='ui-btn-left' data-icon='arrow-l' onclick="history.back();  $('#pagecontent').empty(); $('#headerDiv h1').text(''); return false">Back</a>
              <a data-rel='external' data-ajax="false" href='' class='ui-btn-right' data-icon='home'>Home</a>
              <h1></h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" id="pagecontent" ></div>
        <div class="footerDate" data-role="footer" data-theme="b"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: how are u removing history.back() exactly?

Comment: How about just using data-rel="back" on an anchor instead ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by instead of redirecting when the user clicks the back button, update the page itself using jQuery - set each individual div items data. This is fine for me since there is not much being displayed on the page, but for pages with a large amount of divs and different content it may not be usable.